# How to access web element in atomac?

Tags: python, macos, pyatom

```
<Application>
<Window>    
<AXScrollArea:"">
        <AXWebArea:"">
            <AXGroup>
               <AXGroup:"">
                  <AXButton:"NEW">
```

Above is the element Tree which I can see, I want to click the button. Can anyone please help me to do it?

```
window.activate() 
allUIElements=window.findAllR(AXRole='AXGroup') 
callListItems=allUIElements[0].AXChildren[0].AXChildren[0].‌AXChildren[0].AXChil‌​dren
buttonsInRow=callListItems[logic].findAllR(AXRole='AXButton‌​')
```

Comment: window.activate()
 allUIElements=window.findAllR(AXRole='AXGroup')
 callListItems=allUIElements[0].AXChildren[0].AXChildren[0].AXChildren[0].AXChildren
 buttonsInRow=callListItems[logic].findAllR(AXRole='AXButton')

Comment: Please post additional required information in your question by clicking the "edit" button below your question, not as a comment.

Comment: Please use proper spelling and punctuation.  Even if English is not your first language, the effort to make it pleasant to read helps a lot.

Comment: Did you manage to do it? @jithendrak.s

Comment: Yes one needs to enter into webarea and then get into tree structure